# File name autocompletion stopped working in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I just noticed this.  Previously, when I typed `cd Doc<tab>` I would get `cd Documents`.  Now I get `cd Doc`.  If I hit `tab` again it just appends more tabs.  I only have one `Doc*` directory:

```
$ ls -d Doc*
Documents/
```

Is there a way I can get this working again?  I believe it was working until recently.  I recently updated the command-line tools.  Could this have affected this?

I am on Yosemite on a Retina MacBook.

Comment: which Shell are you using? do you have several files/folders "Doc*", so that autocompletion does not know which to pick?

Comment: Does hitting the `Tab` key a second time return a match? If so, you could have multiple matches. The Xcode command-line tools *should* impact the behaviour of your shell.

Comment: @CML, I am using `/bin/sh`.  I had switched to it to do some testing.  Switching it back to `/bin/bash` fixes it.  Thanks!